# Some error in my mysql_fetch_assoc

Tags: php

I am trying to create a rumour-based website. In one part of the site, there is a working feature where you are post rumours and the rumours are shown.

But i am working on the homepage so that the two latest rumours are placed into a table. With my code below, there is a table with no rows, despite data being in the mysql table, and this error message:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage22/th/eq/li/theqlick.com/public_html/leeds.php on line 212

Any idea? My code is below:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM rumour ORDER BY id DESC";
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query); 
$id = $row['id'];
$name = $row['name'];
$description = $row['description'];

echo "<table class ='rumour' border='1'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td style = 'font-size:18pt;font-family:Noteworthy-Bold;'> Hot Rumours  </td>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class = 'td1'>". text2link($row['description']). "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class = 'td1'>". text2link($row['description']). "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: You need to modify the line at `$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rumour ORDER BY id DESC");`

Comment: You need to have mysql_fetch_assoc on your results than query - 

$result = mysql_query($sql);   and then $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)

Comment: Also you need to stop using `mysql_*` functions and go with `pdo` or `mysqli_*`

Answer (score 0):

You're posting a string into mysql_fetch_assoc, and not a mysql_query...

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM rumour ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Should be

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rumour ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Answer (score 0):

The [manual for that function](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) says:

```
array mysql_fetch_assoc ( resource $result )
```

You are passing it a string containing a query, not the result of running a query.

You need to pass it through [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/mysql_query) first.

… at least you do if you continue using `mysql_*`, which you shouldn't.  It is [obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and you should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Answer (score 0):

Use are directly using $query in mysql_fetch_assoc($query) which is string type.
You forget to get result. Use this instead:

```
$query="Your query here";
$result=msqyl_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forget to execute you query using `mysql_query` function

Try this code may be help you

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM rumour ORDER BY id DESC";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```